# NASM iterate over string and stop when finds certain value

Tags: string, assembly, iteration, x86-64, nasm

This question is similar to others, but it is not a duplicate. I am learning NASM (assembly).
My program has the following goal. I give as input a word (e.g "aab"). I want to compare each char in the string to a predefined value. 
Here is a snippet.

```
    ;try to compare
    xor rax,rax ;set iteration index to 0
    lea rsi, [userpass]
back_to_loop:
    cmp rsi, 'a'
    je _exit
    inc rsi ;increase index
    jmp back_to_loop
```

!!!A good help would be editing the program in such a way, that the iteration would stop as soon as it finds an 'a' in the string. If I found how that is done, I could modify it to my own needs.

My entire effort so far:

```
 section    .text
    global _start
_start:   
;read input
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rsi, userpass
    mov rdx, rax
    add rdx, 0x64 ; 100 
    syscall

    ;try to compare
    xor rax,rax ;set iteration index to 0
    lea rsi, [userpass]
back_to_loop:
    cmp rsi, 'a'
    je _exit
    inc rsi ;increase index
    jmp back_to_loop

_exit:
   mov  rax, 1
   xor  rbx, rbx
   int  80h

section .bss     
   num resb 64  
section .data
   userpass times 100 db 0 ;input
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `REPNE SCASB`? Look those up in Intel's manual.

Comment: You're comparing the pointer against `'a'`, not the pointed-to byte in memory `byte [rsi]`.  And BTW, this search is what `memchr` does, if you ever want to look for a more efficient implementation.